# What is a replacement function for windows.createPopup()?

Tags: html, popup, mozilla

Some functions (`dropdown`, ..) doesn't work in Mozilla and IE11. I think it's because I used `windows.CreatePopup()`. How can I replace it, and with what function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

createPopup is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use a [div](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [iframe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or other element with a relatively high [z-index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value. For info, see [Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) changes.

There's an example on [the page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).